# One entry point of application to check session?

Tags: angular

How to create one entry point in application for checking expired session?
It should be place, that calls each time, when user walk throughout application.

Does Angular JS have special mechanism for that?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: I am not sure, that I need routing

Comment: Then other option ngInit

Comment: Why you posted link on own profile?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I can not do checking in each component in ngInit